# Send Registered Users Email with QueryString to Login Page while redirecting in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Asp.Net Developement, I am stuck at a problem, I want to send the users email, through query string while redirecting them to Login Page. Please Can anyone help me.

This is the code which I have wrote till now.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register(int id = 0)
        {
            UserDetail usermodel = new UserDetail();
            return View(usermodel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(UserDetail userDetail)
        {
            using (dbModels user = new dbModels())
            {
                if (user.UserDetails.Any(x => x.Email == userDetail.Email))
                {
                    ViewBag.EmailExists = "Email Already Exists";
                    return View("Register");
                }

                userDetail.Status = 1;
                userDetail.created_at = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                user.UserDetails.Add(userDetail);
                user.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View("Login", new UserDetail());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View("Login");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question , Instead of the code

```
return View("Login", new UserDetail());
```

try using the code as below

```
return RedirectToAction ("Login", new { email = userDetail.Email });
```

Comment: @DebjitRoy , please tick up the answer as correct if you think. Many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectToAction` in Register post action to redirect to Login page and passing query string as `userEmail` and assigning to user register email id to it. You'll get the  user email id at login page(check by debugging)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register(int id = 0)
    {
        UserDetail usermodel = new UserDetail();
        return View(usermodel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(UserDetail userDetail)
    {
        using (dbModels user = new dbModels())
        {
            if (user.UserDetails.Any(x => x.Email == userDetail.Email))
            {
                ViewBag.EmailExists = "Email Already Exists";
                return View("Register");
            }

            userDetail.Status = 1;
            userDetail.created_at = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            user.UserDetails.Add(userDetail);
            user.SaveChanges();
        }
        ModelState.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", new { userEmail = userDetail.Email });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string userEmail)
    {
        /* Your code userEmail parameter*/

        return View("Login");
    }
```